# putting variables value into .text

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, textfield

How can I input varables value into a textfield?

```
var i:uint=0

for(i; i<4; i++){
pageText.text=i+1
}
```

If i use i+"something" then it can get the i value, but other than that it could not get i value.

Comment: so i used var extra:int=1 and change to pagesText.text=i+extra+"" to get the amount i want, but is there any other more 'correct' way without using +""(nothing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text property of TextField is expecting a string. Use toString to convert the int.

```
var i:uint=0

for(i; i<4; i++){
    pageText.text=i.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var pageText:TextField = new TextField();
var i:uint=0
this.addchild(pageText)

for(i; i<4; i++)
{
    pageText.text=i
}
```